# WP Custom Registration Form

Tags: wordpress, customization, custom-wordpress-pages

How can I create from scratch or modify WP registration form, without using any plugin?
Can't find any recourse in web. All with plugins.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is off topic: See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You are expected to have ***researched your issue and made attempts to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you have a *specific* question, it should include details of what you have tried so far and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically create a plugin from scratch to be able to make a custom contact form - see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Your plugin will need to show a form, i.e:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="contact_form.php">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />
    <input type="text" name="last_name" />
    <textarea rows="10" name="message" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And then in your

contact_form.php

do something similar to:

```
$first = $_POST['first_name'];
$last = $_POST['last_name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$email = "Name: " . $first . " Last name: " . $last . " Message: " . $message;

$to = "youremail@yourdomain.com";
$subject = "New message from " . $first . " " . $last;
$body = $email;
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
```

I hope this manages to help you out!

Learning how to build WP plugins will help you immensely in the future, so it'll be worth diving into the WP docs to get a broader knowledge of the subject. Best of luck! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_register_form' );
function myplugin_register_form() {

    $first_name = ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) ? trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) : '';

        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="first_name"><?php _e( 'First Name', 'mydomain' ) ?><br />
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_unslash( $first_name ) ); ?>" size="25" /></label>
        </p>
        <?php
    }

    //2. Add validation. In this case, we make sure first_name is required.
    add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
    function myplugin_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

        if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) && trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) == '' ) {
            $errors->add( 'first_name_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a first name.', 'mydomain' ) );
        }

        return $errors;
    }

    //3. Finally, save our extra registration user meta.
    add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_user_register' );
    function myplugin_user_register( $user_id ) {
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) );
        }
    }
```